# Nintex Forms, Populate choice field based on user selection

Tags: 2013

I'm developing a form using SP2013 and Nintex Forms.

Right now what I've got is two choice fields and depending on the selection made by the user in a previous field I show one and hide the other.

What I would really like to do is to have just one choice field and populate it based on the previous selection made by the user.

Is this posible? Any ideas on how to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Create 2 lists with a mapping as 1:N relationship i.e. one list is **States** and another is **Cities** where relationship is 1 state has many cities.
2. In NINTEX form, add a List Lookup control from the SharePoint category of the Form Controls...select a SharePoint list (i.e. State) as the Source List drop-down, and click Save.
3. Add another List Lookup control from the SharePoint category of the Form Controls...select another list (i.e. Cities) from the Source List drop-down.
4. Expand the Filtering section and select By a controls value from the Filter available selections drop-down.

Please click [here](https://community.nintex.com/docs/DOC-1201) for the detail demo.